# Save energy in plane changing orbital maneuver

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, cassini

I just read about [Cassini's upcoming orbital maneuvers](http://astronomynow.com/2016/11/23/saturn-probe-prepares-for-dramatic-ring-grazing-orbits/) where there's a nice [animation showing Cassini's orbits](https://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/system/news_items/main_images/2966_CSM_Traj_wFR_RevC.gif). Here's a frame of the animation:

[image: Cassini orbits]

I see a lot of plane changes, i.e. the probe's orbital plane is rotated very often with respect to its previous revolution. I always thought that these maneuvers are very expensive (need to spend quite a lot of fuel): you need to fire around the point where you want the old and new orbits to "touch", the plane change axis, and from what I remember from the days when I was playing KSP that these involve quite a lot of delta-v.

So how are the Cassini people able to pull that off? Either they do have more than enough fuel left to spend it that way, or there must be a way reduce the cost of these maneuvers that I'm not aware of yet.

Is there a way to reduce the amount of fuel spent to rotate the orbital plane to such extreme degrees?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Titan. This is all done using gravity assists from Saturn's largest moon, Titan. Only tiny amounts of propellant are used to target the Titan flybys.

Comment: Very clever. I was able to find a [few](https://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/gravity-assists/) [articles](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/04/20/science/space/20cassini.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0) about that.